When I compile a shared object, how do I determine what exact requirements the shared object has?
When I compile (Rust source into) a shared object (an .so file, to be used as a shared library by some other binary), how do I determine what exact requirements the shared object has? More specifically, how do I determine what will be (prior to building, based on knowledge of the build system) or is (after building, based on what was emitted) the minimum required version of the backwards compatible C standard library in a Rust program that only depends on standard libraries (of Rust and/or C)?
For example, it seems that when I build a binary from a simple Rust program that only writes a greeting to standard output, the shared object may or may not require GLIBC v2.33, depending on whether I build the binary on Debian 11 or 12. I do understand that the requirement for some specific GLIBC version comes from that the shared object refers to something specific on the system that it's being built on, but what I don't know is how do I determine that a given shared object's minimum required GLIBC version is e.g. 2.33, if that were the case.
Building the shared object, referencing versioned stuff on the current system:
rustc --crate-type=dylib src/lib.rs

src/lib.rs:
pub fn greet_to_stdout() {
    println!("Hello world");
}

Checking of linking issues for the built shared object:
ldd liblib.so

Let's define the systems as follows:

Debian 11 = Docker image rust@sha256:4ddb21b979def540e0c7d686ec92fd271e44200f1273551b0b248032e573377a
Debian 12 = Docker image rust@sha256:3aee2d2979c2ddb4de910a38f1e91ca162475a67754fb07e2bb74661fd859efe

If I build the shared object on Debian 11, no linking issues arise on Debian 11 nor on Debian 12. If I build it on Debian 12 (emitting bookworm.so), there are no issues linking on Debian 12, but on Debian 11 there will be a problem with incompatible GLIBC:
./bookworm.so: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by ./bookworm.so)
./bookworm.so: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by ./bookworm.so)
./bookworm.so: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by ./bookworm.so)

What I've tried:

Checking ldd version on the building system to predict the minimum required GLIBC version of the emitted shared object. This doesn't answer the question, because ldd version does not seem to match what the shared object will require. For example, on Debian 12, there is ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.36-9+deb12u3) 2.36, but the shared object depends on 2.32, 2.33 and 2.34 for some reason as seen above, and on Debian 11 there is ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.31-13+deb11u7) 2.31, and I have no clue what version of GLIBC my shared object requires when built there!
Parsing the shared object as ELF and grepping for any mentions of GLIBC: This way I get at least some clues that 2.33 is referenced to on the thing built on Debian 12 but not on the thing built on Debian 11. But I still don't know how to reliably determine the minimum requirements for my shared object, or how to control them in an ergonomic and predictable way. Hopping between operating systems until a compatible binary is spit out certainly doesn't feel good.


How did you install Rust?

You can see the versions used by a compiled executable with readelf --version-info foo.
See also: https://johannst.github.io/notes/development/symbolver.html
